# insert statement one column from another table rest of the columns is values

Tags: sql, sql-server

would like to know how to write SQL query, when you want to use the insert statment and fill it with 2 values and then a value from a external table?

Something like this.

```
INSERT INTO [PPLAT_KPI].[dbo].[KPI_Values]
       (TS,
       Value,
       ID)
 VALUES
       ('2010-02-04'
       ,'200',
           SELECT KPI_Parameter.ID
         FROM [PPLAT_KPI].[dbo].[KPI_Parameter] 
            where KPI_Parameter.Site = 'XXX' and KPI_Parameter.Plant = 'vv';)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try:

```
INSERT INTO [PPLAT_KPI].[dbo].[KPI_Values]
       (TS,
       Value,
       ID)
SELECT 
      '2010-02-04',
      '200',
      KPI_Parameter.ID
FROM [PPLAT_KPI].[dbo].[KPI_Parameter] 
where KPI_Parameter.Site = 'XXX' and KPI_Parameter.Plant = 'vv';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use INSERT INTO...SELECT like this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp